# File includes from Linux to Windows

Tags: php, linux, windows

I have faced the problem. The script is written in Linux environment and i am using windows. When i have downloaded the entire script, the includes has stopped working. Example:

```
<?PHP
include("/var/www/keytarget.adnet.lt/data/core/php/class/CurrentVersionNumber/main.php");

if (VERSION_NUMBER) {
    include("/var/www/keytarget.adnet.lt/data/version/" . VERSION_NUMBER . "/php/class/KeytargetLocalCacheSingleton.php");
    include("/var/www/keytarget.adnet.lt/data/version/" . VERSION_NUMBER . "/php/class/KeytargetPdo.php");
    include("/var/www/keytarget.adnet.lt/data/version/" . VERSION_NUMBER . "/php/class/Receiver.php");
    $currentKeywordReceiver = new Receiver("HTML");
}
?>
```

Any ideas of how can i replace include URLs so that it would be windows URL ? Like C:\wamp\www\data or something similar ?

Comment: open your editor -> search end replace -> type in search pattern -> type n replacement -> hit enter?

Comment: You don't need to change the directory seperators - PHP on windows will happily resilve a path usng '/' as a directory seperator. (OTOH the repeated, hard-coded absloute path is very bad practice and the right way to fix the problem would be to start by hitting the developer over the head repeatedly).

Comment: I would also suggest you to install Linux on your own laptop. You'll learn a lot, and it is much simpler to develop for a Linux server.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, especially thanks PeeHaa for sarcasm, i apreaciate it. I resolved the problem simply putting the project files to c:/var/www/keytarget.adnet.lt/data/version/...
As windows opens "/" dir as c:/, so the problem resolved by simply puting the project files to that directory and configuring apache server with some aliases. Thank you all, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Download some text editor and replace all occurrences.

Or use a php script that will replace it. And it's a good practice to don't use the full path and use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] instead.

The php script should like something like this:

```
<?php
  $toreplace = "/var/www/"; // the old path to root
  $replace = "C:/wamp/www/data"; // the new path to root
  foreach(glob("*.php") as $php_file) {
    $data = file_get_contents($php_file);
    $data = str_replace($toreplace,$replace,$data);
    file_put_contents($php_file,$data);
  }
?>
```